# Place 2 textboxes on the same line, have to use inline-block

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I had to place one div to the right of a centered one, and now I have a problem with my textboxes. They are one seperate lines, not the same anymore.

This is what it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKr4d.png

This is the code that I have:

```
            <!-- Logo -->
            <div>
                <asp:Image ID="img_logo" runat="server" ImageAlign="Middle" Width="200px" Height="200px"/>
            </div>

            <!-- Search Textboxes -->
            <div style="display: inline-block; margin-top: 1%">
                <asp:TextBox ID="tb_what" runat="server" CssClass="Textbox" style="margin-left: 1%"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tb_where" runat="server" CssClass="Textbox"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>

            <!-- Search Button -->
            <div style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 0; height: 0; vertical-align: top;">
                <div style="background: black; display: inline-block; position: absolute;">
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="btn_search" runat="server" style="margin-top: 1%" ImageUrl="http://png-5.findicons.com/files/icons/772/token_light/256/search.png" CssClass="Button" Width="40px" Height="40px"/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Login & Register -->
            <div>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lb_login" runat="server" Font-Names="Segoe UI" Font-Underline="false" style="margin-right: 1%">Login</asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lb_registrer" runat="server" Font-Names="Segoe UI" Font-Underline="false">Registrer</asp:LinkButton>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I appreciate your help and time!

Best regards
Marcus

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this maybe:
http://jsfiddle.net/y8wje2jL/

- Remove the inline style from the input
- Set property to the outside div (`display, width, text-align`)
- Set property to each input (`width, display`)

hope it works well for you.

ps: if it causes a problem with the button, you can set `position relative` to the div that contains the input and then offset the button using `position: absolute` with `negative top`

Answer (score 0):

**Working Fiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/y8wje2jL/1/

```
   <div class="test">
      <input type="textBox" ID="tb_what" runat="server" CssClass="Textbox"/>             
      <input type="textBox" ID="tb_where" runat="server" CssClass="Textbox1"/>       
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.test{
    width:400px;;
    display:table;
    text-align: center;
}
.textbox,Textbox1{
    width:40%;
    display:inline-block;
    background:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-                
beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-
beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">  
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
  <input type="textBox" ID="tb_what" runat="server" CssClass="Textbox"/>
</div>
<div class="col">             
  <input type="textBox" ID="tb_where" runat="server" CssClass="Textbox1"/>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```